# Silverlight Domain Service - Delete Validations

Tags: validation, silverlight, crud

How can I perform constraint validations with Silverlight + Domain Service + EF

Table1 is a primary table

Table1 is a FK in Table2

I need to validate when deleting Table1, that Table2 has no records related with Table1.

I Table2 has records related then throw an exception.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is the backing data store? If SQL Server you should set the constraint in the database and EF will take them into account (Or at least throw an exception when you break a server rule, if you have not updated EF).

Answer (score 1):

In your DomainService, just add a **validation attribute** on the delete method,

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(MyCustomValidator), "CustomDeleteTable1Validation")]
public void DeleteTable1(Table1 table1)
{
    //normal behavior
    if ((table1.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
    {
        this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(table1, EntityState.Deleted);
    }
    else
    {
        this.ObjectContext.Table1s.Attach(table1);
        this.ObjectContext.Table1s.DeleteObject(table1);
    }
}
```

and then do whatever you want in the validation method

```
public static class MyCustomValidator
    {
        public static ValidationResult CustomDeleteTable1Validation(Table1 table1, ValidationContext context)
        {
            // check your values ...
            var isOk=true;
            // and ...
            if(isOk)
                 return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                 return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " error");
        }
    }
```

enjoy !